# How to import the given file?

Tags: import, data

Consider a file with the following block structure:

```
Event XX Muon YY:
data
End of event
Event XX' Muon YY':
data'
End of Event
...
```

where `data` is some dataset.

Is it possible to import such a file in the form of the following array:

```
XX YY data
XX' YY' data'
...
```

An example of the file is given below:

```
Event 579 Muon 103:
DecayVacuum_block1_0 -59.70285441316312 -11.036168992861251 -2427.058656624044 0.006298803597993789 12.988555908203125 7.6875 18.069478857455444 0.6584001421142602 0.08786208907228883 6.908344436247385 False False 1.0 0 1 0 -59.325958251953125 -10.744438171386719 -2479.03369140625 T1Lidbox_1 -211 211 57.90705871582031 50.38629913330078 57.90813069937492 50.39601779535441 -13 -13 103 8.02 0.015148748410865664 768 320
103 1 -59.325958251953125 -10.744438171386719 -2479.03369140625 T1Lidbox_1 3.016469955444336 -0.06643134355545044 -218.59584045410156 218.61668767860326 0 -13
103 2 -59.325958251953125 -10.744438171386719 -2479.03369140625 T1Lidbox_1 -0.9576877951622009 -0.20693859457969666 50.38629913330078 50.39601779535441 0 211
103 3 -59.325958251953125 -10.744438171386719 -2479.03369140625 T1Lidbox_1 -0.29368579387664795 -0.13572342693805695 57.90705871582031 57.90813069937492 0 -211
103 4 -59.325958251953125 -10.744438171386719 -2479.03369140625 T1Lidbox_1 -1.5919358730316162 0.01566511206328869 110.2023696899414 110.21391905794624 0 -13
103 5 -88.69776916503906 -21.007896423339844 3629.83740234375 LeadTile2_47 -0.22401176393032074 0.13002203404903412 6.7392497062683105 6.745669234149708 3 -211
103 6 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 -0.42545315623283386 -0.003640354610979557 0.3338720202445984 0.5585463092988446 5 -211
103 7 -112.54698944091797 -22.38661766052246 3671.681884765625 Hcal_1 -0.4936700761318207 0.06373818218708038 0.4781147539615631 1.1658256664829363 6 2112
103 8 -123.22480010986328 -21.007997512817383 3682.023193359375 Hcal_1 -0.28808534145355225 -0.16402196884155273 0.36775708198547363 1.0620379975837424 7 2112
103 9 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 0.11317602545022964 -0.07085563242435455 0.4059564173221588 0.4481613855729009 5 111
103 10 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 0.07441836595535278 -0.009844702668488026 0.34658995270729065 0.3546260095928353 9 22
103 11 -89.05522155761719 -20.898391723632812 3652.631591796875 LeadTile2_120 0.026991134509444237 -0.0030921336729079485 0.11994204670190811 0.12298145518598066 10 -11
103 12 -89.05522155761719 -20.898391723632812 3652.631591796875 LeadTile2_120 0.04879576712846756 -0.006259504705667496 0.22635973989963531 0.23164455801099038 10 11
103 13 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 0.20005565881729126 0.1437157839536667 1.0877169370651245 1.1239592705074106 5 -211
103 14 -88.51561737060547 -20.1934871673584 3656.058349609375 LeadTile2_131 -0.1636590212583542 -0.007074369583278894 0.46632620692253113 1.0616390723523434 13 2112
103 15 -91.81292724609375 -20.336017608642578 3665.45361328125 Hcal_1 0.03333818167448044 0.02326338179409504 0.45641598105430603 1.0441850946230768 14 2212
103 16 -88.51561737060547 -20.1934871673584 3656.058349609375 LeadTile2_131 0.3463969826698303 0.4674844443798065 0.43424779176712036 1.1873865363615275 13 2112
103 17 -81.11677551269531 -10.208284378051758 3665.33349609375 Hcal_1 0.4825921356678009 0.4339957535266876 0.24390113353729248 1.1676978689569182 16 2112
103 18 -55.82482147216797 12.536803245544434 3678.115966796875 Hcal_1 0.324808806180954 0.5985442996025085 0.04506365582346916 1.1602332166495282 17 2212
103 19 -88.51561737060547 -20.1934871673584 3656.058349609375 LeadTile2_131 -0.5540199279785156 0.5081797242164612 -0.35060909390449524 1.2533533085960697 13 2112
103 20 -93.40139770507812 -15.71196174621582 3652.96630859375 LeadTile2_121 -0.332576185464859 0.5430411696434021 -0.10555848479270935 1.1399238095223332 19 2112
103 21 -953.5825805664062 1013.046142578125 3502.44189453125 rockD_1 -0.34888577461242676 0.46342331171035767 -0.1325988471508026 1.1121366690148184 20 2112
103 22 -956.9946899414062 1017.578369140625 3501.14501953125 rockD_1 -0.38570085167884827 0.4363413453102112 -0.10547628998756409 1.1093414754456066 21 2212
103 23 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 -0.17379210889339447 0.5633984208106995 1.086050033569336 1.5516057804361711 5 2212
103 24 -90.04611206054688 -18.519445419311523 3655.73046875 LeadTile2_130 -0.718821108341217 0.19321556389331818 0.5590537190437317 1.322633799448011 23 2112
103 25 -94.03666687011719 -17.44680404663086 3658.834228515625 LeadTile2_140 -0.5999429821968079 0.06679429113864899 0.49571433663368225 1.2218464836051341 24 2112
103 26 -98.15168762207031 -16.98866081237793 3662.234375 Hcal_1 -0.5163719654083252 -0.2267114222049713 0.4111629128456116 1.1704170552652122 25 2112
103 27 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 -0.2882811427116394 -0.3462800681591034 3.5342562198638916 3.5654174526785245 5 111
103 28 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 -0.1668267548084259 -0.2658022940158844 2.0288240909576416 2.052951343231037 27 22
103 29 -89.49765014648438 -21.046911239624023 3652.589111328125 LeadTile2_120 -0.16185806691646576 -0.259988933801651 1.9835622310638428 2.0070654361898828 28 11
103 30 -89.60833740234375 -21.244556427001953 3654.1708984375 LeadTile2_125 -0.02107236534357071 -0.05223633721470833 0.4087047278881073 0.41256785394026213 29 22
103 31 -89.72205352783203 -21.526439666748047 3656.37646484375 LeadTile2_132 -0.007515617646276951 -0.01951507292687893 0.15430068969726562 0.1557121913687522 30 -11
103 32 -89.72205352783203 -21.526439666748047 3656.37646484375 LeadTile2_132 -0.013325988315045834 -0.03243802860379219 0.25444990396499634 0.2568556450848018 30 11
103 33 -89.5932388305664 -21.209577560424805 3653.887939453125 LeadTile2_124 -0.010133491829037666 -0.021490365266799927 0.18179777264595032 nan 29 22
103 34 -89.63020324707031 -21.287975311279297 3654.55126953125 LeadTile2_126 -0.00784902274608612 -0.01739034429192543 0.1465730518102646 0.14781052692381355 33 11
103 35 -89.56925201416016 -21.165510177612305 3653.52783203125 LeadTile2_123 -0.030253421515226364 -0.04851561784744263 0.3983611762523651 0.40244336425597205 29 22
103 36 -89.64429473876953 -21.285844802856445 3654.515869140625 LeadTile2_126 -0.025957126170396805 -0.03879397362470627 0.32807591557502747 0.3313801627872035 35 -11
103 37 -89.52398681640625 -21.09075164794922 3652.924560546875 LeadTile2_121 -0.05257654935121536 -0.08682318031787872 0.6697489619255066 0.677396656459482 29 22
103 38 -89.6243667602539 -21.25650978088379 3654.203125 LeadTile2_125 -0.04865559563040733 -0.08089394122362137 0.6301157474517822 0.6371477952715674 37 11
103 39 -90.1339111328125 -22.402902603149414 3661.717041015625 Hcal_1 -0.0018571860855445266 -0.02257460542023182 0.1173102855682373 0.11947704821486378 38 22
103 40 -89.7898178100586 -21.45747947692871 3655.7998046875 LeadTile2_130 -0.010960398241877556 -0.012866056524217129 0.10362830013036728 0.10499757296249462 38 22
103 41 -89.3776626586914 -20.855737686157227 3651.1298828125 TvTile2_229 -0.1214543804526329 -0.08047778159379959 1.5054320096969604 nan 27 22
103 42 -89.55453491210938 -20.972938537597656 3653.322265625 ScTile2_123 -0.0845247209072113 -0.05622992292046547 1.048455834388733 1.0533594497889684 41 -11
103 43 -89.90038299560547 -21.28132438659668 3657.935302734375 LeadTile2_137 -0.008341298438608646 -0.0025697287637740374 0.1013646200299263 0.1017397019819335 42 22
103 44 -89.7550277709961 -21.1678524017334 3656.09912109375 LeadTile2_131 -0.012116490863263607 -0.017255468294024467 0.19086869060993195 nan 42 22
103 45 -90.62996673583984 -22.41387939453125 3669.8818359375 Hcal_1 -0.006325222551822662 -0.009636974893510342 0.10792633146047592 0.10854139241692716 44 11
End of event
Event 2349 Muon 103:
DecayVacuum_block1_0 -60.969564687377435 -11.593466041824653 -2421.4118877575133 0.006298803597993789 12.988555908203125 7.6875 16.99922908311631 0.5607433764960206 0.6527958193819055 3.0962135146752705 True False 0.010000000000000009 1 1 0 -59.33159255981445 -10.744314193725586 -2478.62548828125 T1Lidbox_1 -211 211 26.736848831176758 13.327919006347656 26.741718600671877 13.332855440318848 -13 -13 103 8.02 0.06059624068439007 278 120
103 1 -59.33159255981445 -10.744314193725586 -2478.62548828125 T1Lidbox_1 3.016469955444336 -0.06643134355545044 -218.59584045410156 218.61668767860326 0 -13
103 2 -59.33159255981445 -10.744314193725586 -2478.62548828125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.1687319427728653 0.28923848271369934 13.327919006347656 13.332855440318848 0 211
103 3 -59.33159255981445 -10.744314193725586 -2478.62548828125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.31043481826782227 -0.38023510575294495 26.736848831176758 26.741718600671877 0 -211
103 4 -59.33159255981445 -10.744314193725586 -2478.62548828125 T1Lidbox_1 -2.4468164443969727 0.05356593802571297 178.51512145996094 178.5319286108239 0 -13
103 5 -131.4512481689453 -92.88449096679688 3603.236328125 T6Lid_1 0.21759210526943207 0.426509827375412 0.26712551712989807 1.0867232139816851 3 2212
103 6 -131.4512481689453 -92.88449096679688 3603.236328125 T6Lid_1 -0.2044437974691391 -0.7036125659942627 1.8508656024932861 1.9955077552443752 3 211
103 7 -144.5005340576172 -116.862060546875 3676.145751953125 Hcal_1 -0.38729825615882874 0.33661219477653503 -0.04765758290886879 1.0704827410500564 6 2212
103 8 -144.5005340576172 -116.862060546875 3676.145751953125 Hcal_1 -0.10732777416706085 -0.38572221994400024 0.3896907866001129 1.0931344189830194 6 2112
103 9 -147.68170166015625 -128.29473876953125 3687.696044921875 Hcal_1 -0.07755265384912491 -0.41723012924194336 0.1595889776945114 1.0432387566640802 8 2112
103 10 -144.5005340576172 -116.862060546875 3676.145751953125 Hcal_1 -0.04303813725709915 0.2628801465034485 0.573736310005188 1.1315855914971635 6 2212
103 11 -144.5005340576172 -116.862060546875 3676.145751953125 Hcal_1 -0.5061129331588745 -0.02835562638938427 0.4105550944805145 1.1438063188322853 6 2112
103 12 -144.5005340576172 -116.862060546875 3676.145751953125 Hcal_1 -0.26829180121421814 -0.22035817801952362 -0.06405741721391678 0.3796332220946274 6 211
103 13 -131.4512481689453 -92.88449096679688 3603.236328125 T6Lid_1 0.3474636971950531 -0.16186915338039398 0.8522919416427612 0.944888358946551 3 -211
103 14 -89.15900421142578 -99.92935180664062 3695.212646484375 Hcal_1 -0.18618591129779816 0.4343188405036926 0.025961406528949738 1.052024291615631 13 2112
103 15 -131.4512481689453 -92.88449096679688 3603.236328125 T6Lid_1 0.08798656612634659 0.7213903665542603 7.485574722290039 7.521980676732306 3 111
103 16 -131.4512481689453 -92.88447570800781 3603.236572265625 T6Lid_1 -0.03626123443245888 0.14526064693927765 1.5588064193725586 1.5659798803780591 15 22
103 17 -131.7501678466797 -91.68704223632812 3616.08642578125 LeadTile2_3 -0.016280310228466988 0.06542555242776871 0.6983613967895508 0.7016084756167978 16 -11
103 18 -131.79483032226562 -91.50151824951172 3618.322509765625 LeadTile2_10 -0.0014094897778704762 0.011693130247294903 0.13387292623519897 0.13439001575708354 17 22
103 19 -131.79025268554688 -91.54283905029297 3617.73583984375 LeadTile2_8 -0.0004590509633999318 0.012512938119471073 0.15493659675121307 nan 17 22
End of event
Event 4853 Muon 103:
DecayVacuum_block1_0 -60.6301598604297 -10.789843121298905 -2386.051380819185 0.006298803597993789 12.988555908203125 7.6875 18.56888487891804 1.2623359815515869 0.1274715850358829 5.231242867844793 True False 1.0000000000000098e-22 11 1 0 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 321 -321 41.26478958129883 73.19168090820312 41.27471041334095 73.19734585997665 -13 -13 103 8.02 3.030286294495454 720 329
103 1 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 3.016469955444336 -0.06643134355545044 -218.59584045410156 218.61668767860326 0 -13
103 2 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.7547829747200012 -0.1259859800338745 73.19168090820312 73.19734585997665 0 -321
103 3 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.7580353021621704 -0.022935261949896812 41.26478958129883 41.27471041334095 0 321
103 4 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -1.1621145009994507 0.04731705039739609 94.92681121826172 94.9339949685971 0 -13
103 5 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.7203018069267273 0.018894435837864876 3.533877372741699 3.6402194918803956 0 321
103 6 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.09451156854629517 -0.1545814573764801 0.2316783219575882 0.32554952419132394 0 -211
103 7 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.3496589958667755 0.009996508248150349 1.5533064603805542 1.598312262266069 0 211
103 8 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 0.7649329304695129 0.2625168561935425 2.6809680461883545 3.096537493972363 0 3312
103 9 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 0.2720939517021179 -0.058406487107276917 0.4951633810997009 0.5849042610150575 0 211
103 10 -59.33674621582031 -10.744200706481934 -2478.251953125 T1Lidbox_1 -0.21409180760383606 0.08961568772792816 0.7175712585449219 0.9035455018652363 0 130
103 11 -106.47944641113281 8.98904037475586 -2320.243896484375 LiScY_210220_210222 0.2558553218841553 -0.17366552352905273 0.05524223670363426 0.588466697270301 10 310
End of event
```

Comment: Maybe `ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ StringTrim@StringSplit[StringDelete[text, ":"], "End of event"]` gets close? It's unclear what structure you want returned.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : just a table XX YY data, where data has its own structure.

Comment: So delete the first row or two from each event in the output of my code? (The first row definitely looks different; the second has some data but it's not like the succeeding ones.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = Import["/tmp/data.txt"]; (* Import as "Text" *)

data = ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ 
   StringTrim@StringSplit[StringDelete[text, ":"], "End of event"];

ds = Dataset@ Replace[
   data,
   {{e_, en_, mu_, mun_}, {decay_, ddata__}, data__} :>
     <|e -> en, mu -> mun, decay -> {ddata}, "Data" -> {data}|>,
   1]
```

XX YY:

```
ds[All, {"Event", "Muon"}]
(*
  Dataset[{
    <|"Event" -> 579, "Muon" -> 103|>,
    <|"Event" -> 2349, "Muon" -> 103|>,
    <|"Event" -> 4853, "Muon" -> 103|>}]
*)
```

Data:

```
ds[Select[#Event == 4853 &], "Data"] // Normal // First
(*
{{103, 1, -59.3367, -10.7442, -2478.25, "T1Lidbox_1",...},
 {103, 2, -59.3367, -10.7442, -2478.25, "T1Lidbox_1",...},
 ...
 {103, 11, -106.479, 8.98904, -2320.24, "LiScY_210220_210222",...}}
*)
```